# Hibernate EntityGraph not loading entity graph as declared [Second level]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was trying to use EntityGraph to load Entity.
I have `Employee` entity with all associations mapped as `LAZY` loading associations. At one use case, I want to fetch `Employee` with its single value associations eagerly, so I was trying to use EntityGraph for this.
[I know Eager associations can not be loaded as LAZY using EntityGraph, but in my case, I am trying to load LAZY association EAGERly using Entity graph, which I think should work]

**Employee**

```
    @NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "Employee.graph1", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "firstName") ,
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "lastName"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "manager", subgraph = "managerSubGraph"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "department")
}, subgraphs = {
    @NamedSubgraph(name = "managerSubGraph", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "department"), 
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "manager")}
        )}
    )}
    )
public class Employee {

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Basic
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private Employee manager;
  }
```

**Department**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {

    @Column(name = "id") 
    @Basic
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Set<Employee> employees;

    public Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Caller**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void entityGraphDemo() {

    final EntityGraph<?> entityGraph = em.getEntityGraph("Employee.graph1");

    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph);

    final Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 2, properties);

    // all of these get loaded EAGERly with no issue
    final PersistenceUnitUtil persistenceUnitUtil = entityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitUtil();
    System.out.println("isLoaded(employee, \"department\") = " + persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(employee, "department"));
    System.out.println("isLoaded(employee, \"manager\") = " + persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(employee, "manager"));

    final Employee employeeManager = employee.getManager();

    // these return false, means these nested associations Employee -> Manager -> Department,  Employee -> Manager -> Manager are not loaded (which should be)
    System.out.println("isLoaded(employeeManager, \"department\") = " + persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(employeeManager, "department"));
    System.out.println("isLoaded(employeeManager, \"manager\") = " + persistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded(employeeManager, "manager"));
}
```

First level of entity graph get loaded correctly as expecred, but second level of graph is not getting loaded as expected.
Issue is, `department` and `manager` associations on `employeeManager` (Second level subgraph) are not getting loaded eagerly.

Last two `Syso` prints `false`. Data is available for both associations and when I call getters on `employeeManager` instance, hibernate execute two `sql` to load `manager` and `department`, so both associations seem to load lazily.

So, is there limitations on levels subgraph supported by hibernate? JPA spec does not define any such a limitation. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I see no issue TBH, I followed the same scenario as yours and got true in the last check, Do you have any custom hibernate config?
Also you forgot to post the manager entity

Comment: Just to add a small not releated tip on the entity structure `@JoinColumn` should be defined in one entity side, not both entities Since it marks entity as the owner of the relationship so you should not have 2 owners so you mark one side as `@JoinColumn` and the other side with `mappedBy` property

Comment: @Youans thanks for reply, i agree join Column should be on on side. I’ll try after correcting that. Just to clear, manager is self referencing, so manager association is of type Employee.

Comment: Weird part is, when I try to fetch entity using JPQL instead of EntityManager, I get all data as defined in Entity graph, I mean I get true for last two statements as well.                          em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.id = ?1", Employee.class)
                .setParameter(1, 2)
                .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph)
                .getSingleResult();

Comment: Do you have any custom hibernate config, if so please post them